# How to use Levenberg-Marquardt for parameter identification

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Imagine I have a function called `fun1` that returns a vector of numbers `fun1[a,b,c,d,...]:=`. `{a,b,c,d,...}`  are the parameters to be determined by fitting `fun1[a,b,c,d,...]` to test data. How can I use Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm to minimize $$\left\|\boldsymbol{fun1[a,b,c,d,...]}-\boldsymbol{testdata}\right\|_{2}\text{?}$$

Is something like this correct?

```
findMinimum[fun1[a,b,c,d],Transpose[{param,init}],MaxIterations -> 500, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 8, StepMonitor :> ++steps, 
 Method -> {"LevenbergMarquardt", "Residual" -> Norm[fun1[a,b,c,d]-testvec]}]
```

Comment: This really should have an explicit example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindMinimum` shifts to Levenberg-Marquardt automagically if it detects a sum of squares as objective. But it needs initial conditions:

```
FindMinimum[
 Total[(fun1[a, b, c, d] - testvec)^2], 
 {{a, a0}, {b, b0}, {c,c0}, {d, d0}},
 MaxIterations -> 500,
 PrecisionGoal -> 8,
 StepMonitor :> ++steps
 ]
```

with hopefully good guesses `a0`, `b0`, `c0`, and `d0`.

Better try `NonlinearModelFit`.

Answer (score 4):

[`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) and [`FindFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) are exactly for this purpose and have a lot of useful extra features. Supported methods include "ConjugateGradient", "Gradient", "LevenbergMarquardt", "Newton", "NMinimize", and "QuasiNewton". Please see the examples given in the documentation.

Your example does not have a variable (something like $x$) and it seems *Mathematica* always expects you to have one. In this case I needed an extra wrapping function to get the order of operations correct:

```
fun1[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Table[Total[a { i, b i^2, c i^3, d i^4}], {i, 10}]
data = fun1[1, -5, 1, -0.001];
param = {a, b, c, d};
init = {1, 0, 0, 0};
steps = 0;
Dynamic[steps]
fun2[x_?NumberQ, args__] := fun1[args][[x]]
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, fun2[i, a, b, c, d], 
  Transpose[{param, init}], i, MaxIterations -> 500, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 8, StepMonitor :> ++steps, 
  Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"]
ListPlot[{data, Table[fit[x], {x, 10}]}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Data", "Fit"}]
ListPlot[fit["FitResiduals"], PlotLabel -> "Residuals"]
fit["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

As this was not so elegant, maybe `FindMinimum` is actually a more elegant way of achieving the goal in absence of variables :/